# Foundation 5 Top Bar w/ Centered Logo Building Block on Foundation 6

Tags: html, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, zurb-foundation-6

Foundation 5 building blocks break on Foundation 6. Does anyone know of a work-around? I have tried re-writing the code but Believe I am missing something. Thanks Adolfo

***This is foundation 5 code:***

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .logo-wrapper {
    position: relative; }

  .logo-wrapper .logo {
    width: 92px;
    height: 92px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -46px; }

  .top-bar-section ul.right {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 60px; }

  .top-bar-section ul.right li {
    float: left; }

  .top-bar-section ul.left {
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 60px; }

  .top-bar-section ul.left li {
    float: right; } }
SCSS
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { 

  .logo-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

  .logo-wrapper .logo {
    width: 92px;
    height:  92px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -46px;
  }

  // Right part
  .top-bar-section ul.right {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  
  .top-bar-section ul.right li {
    float:  left;
  }

  // Left part
  .top-bar-section ul.left {
    width:  50%;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }

  .top-bar-section ul.left li {
    float:  right;
  }
}
JS
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="contain-to-grid sticky">

      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
          <li class="name">
            <h1><a class="logo show-for-small-only" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a></h1>
          </li>
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">

          <div class="logo-wrapper hide-for-small-only">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Right Nav Section -->
          <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Left Nav Section -->
          <ul class="left">
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </section>
      </nav>

    </div><!-- /navigation -->
```

***This is what i've tried:***

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
.menu-text {
    display: none !important; } }  
        @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {

            .logo-wrapper {
                position: relative;
            }

            .logo-wrapper .logo {
                width: 92px;
                height:  92px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                right: 50%;
                top: -2px;
                margin-left: -46px;
            }

            // Right part
            .top-bar-section ul.right {
                width: 50%;
                padding-left: 60px;
            }
            
            .top-bar-section ul.right li {
                float:  left;
            }

            // Left part
            .top-bar-section ul.left {
                width:  50%;
                padding-right: 60px;
            }

            .top-bar-section ul.left li {
                float:  right;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
          <li class="name">
            <h1><a class="logo show-for-small-only" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a></h1>
          </li>
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">

          <div class="logo-wrapper hide-for-small-only">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Right Nav Section -->
          <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Left Nav Section -->
          <ul class="left">
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </section>
      </nav>

    </div><!-- /navigation -->
```

Comment: What does "breaks" mean? Be specific. Also, show us what you've tried and why you believe that should fix it and how it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, By breaks I mean does not display properly. I've tried to follow new F6 building blocks code to try to get the f5 building block to work. I'm trying to use the "Top Bar With A Centered Logo And Buttons F5" building block.

Comment: Please put the specific building block's original code in your question along with a link to the building block. Also include what you have tried.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping me through this.

Comment: I can't add the html or css here. Do i open a new question?

Comment: No, you edit the existing question. To add code, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/310951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This building block's components and their classes changed from Foundation 5 to 6. I made this work by using the [Responsive Toggle](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html#responsive-toggle) example from the F6 docs and combined it with the [F5 Building Block](http://zurb.com/building-blocks/top-bar-with-a-centered-logo-and-buttons).

[Working Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/colin-marshall/pen/obBVgW)

### HTML

```html
<!-- Small Navigation -->
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="nav-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <a class="logo-small show-for-small-only" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a>
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<!-- Medium-Up Navigation -->
<nav class="top-bar" id="nav-menu">

  <div class="logo-wrapper hide-for-small-only">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left Nav Section -->
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Right Nav Section -->
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical medium-horizontal" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

### CSS

```css
/* Small Navigation */
.logo-small {
  float: right;
}

.title-bar {
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

.menu-icon,
.title-bar-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

/* Medium-Up Navigation */
@media only screen and (min-width: 40rem) { 

  .logo-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

  .logo-wrapper .logo {
    width: 92px;
    height:  92px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: -6px;
    margin-left: -46px;
  }

  // Right part
  .top-bar-right {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 60px;
  }

  .top-bar-right ul {
    float:  left;
  }

  // Left part
  .top-bar-left {
    width:  50%;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }

  .top-bar-left ul {
    float:  right;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Colin! That worked I really appreciate your help. Thanks, Adolfo